# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'title' of non-object
>   (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\edit.blade.php)

After migration, I face that problem.

edit.blade.file......

```
<input id="title"
  type="text"
  class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" 
  name="title" 
  value="{{ old('title') ?? $user->profile->title }}" required 
  autocomplete="title" autofocus>

 @error('title')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: the error is pretty simple: the profile property of the $user object is null, so you can not get its title

Comment: can you show what `$user` have?do `dd($user);` and let us know what you got?

Comment: Yes... `dd($user->profile)` and verify it contains values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: show me your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can beat it clean with double `??`

```
<input id="title"
  type="text"
  class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" 
  name="title" 
  value="{{ old('title') ?? ($user->profile->title ?? '') }}" required 
  autocomplete="title" autofocus>
```

I have checked `??` for `$user->profile->title` too.

Answer (score 0):

I do this and it's work.

user.php file.....

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent:: boot(); 

        static::created(function($user){
            $user->profile()->create([
                'title'=>$user->username,
            ]);
        });
}
```